# Passing inputs through activities

Tags: android, android-studio

i was developing an app and this question showed up:

```
 EditText inputCorrect = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCorrect);
        EditText inputWrong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputWrong);
        EditText inputBlank = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputBlank);
        EditText inputAll = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputAll);


        String correctAmountText = inputCorrect.getText().toString();
        String wrongAmountText = inputWrong.getText().toString();
        String blankAmountText = inputBlank.getText().toString();
        String allAmountText = inputAll.getText().toString();


    myResultActivty.putExtra("c_a",correctAmountText);
    myResultActivty.putExtra("w_a",wrongAmountText);
    myResultActivty.putExtra("b_a",blankAmountText);
    myResultActivty.putExtra("a_a",allAmountText);
        startActivity(myResultActivty);
```

this is the code there are 4 edit texts with inputType of decimal number
i am getting string from them and send them to other activity.
in the second activity i take those string and turn them into ints with parseint method:

```
String correctNum = inputActivity.getString("c_a");
String wrongNum = inputActivity.getString("w_a");
String blankNum = inputActivity.getString("b_a");
String allNum = inputActivity.getString("a_a");

float res = 0;
int cN = Integer.parseInt(correctNum);
int wN = Integer.parseInt(wrongNum);
int bN = Integer.parseInt(blankNum);
int aN = Integer.parseInt(allNum);
```

but whenever i want to do mathematical operations it crashes or shows zero as result.

Comment: You might want to consider whether these should be separate activities, or whether you should be using a single activity with two fragments or composables for the screens. Beyond that, use Logcat or the debugger to see what values you are getting for your extras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use intents to pass data between activities. In this case, you could create an intent like

```
Intent intent = Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key",10);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int yourNum = extras.getInt("key"); // you should get 10
```